# Chaining of combo boxes in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, image-loading

I am having performance issues in my WPF(MVVM) application. I have 4 combo boxes in a page which shows some Data as well as Images. *ItemsSource* of the first combo(COMBO A) is filled when the constructor of that ViewModel is called and its *SelectedItem* property is set to *FirstOrDefault*. After that, the *ItemsSource* and the *SelectedItem* of the next Combo(COMBO B) is set from the *SelectedItem* property of the first combo(COMBO A). Same applies for COMBO C and COMBO D. Due to this chaining, it takes a long time to load the page. 
Loading all the data is important for me. But a delay in loading of images is acceptable. Can I have a provision where I can load all data at first, then load the View and after loading the view load the images so that user wont feel the lag.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: "Can i have a provision ..." to me sounds like "Give me teh codez plx"-question which is subject to deletion. So again - show us your code

Answer (score 0):

First of you should be sure that the image and data loading(in other words not-a-combo-source-data) is a bottle-neck here.
Please consider to use a kind of performance profiler to check this out. Once you've checked this and found up that it is a bottle-neck , you can separate your combo-source data loading and all other data loading folowing next steps:

1. Get all combo-source related data in C'tor.
2. Use trigger-to-action pattern to move an Onload event handling to your view model(since you have a MVVM).
3. In the Onload event handler invoke all othere(not combo related) data loading. In addition you can consider to use a progress bar while loading heavy data, it will improve the user experience.
4. Use trigger-to-action pattern to move an Onunload event handling to your view model(since you have a MVVM).
5. Inside the Onunload event handler invoke the data clear logic (if needed).
6. It is more simple in case you are using a MVVM framework like Caliburn micro or MVVM light. For example there is an OnActivate handler built-in(Caliburn micro/Screen), you can override this method in your view model and simple move your data loading event into that method and then the data will be refreshed each time the screen will be activated.

That is all, let me know in case you need more explanation.

Best regards.

Comment: please don't encourage the posting of "give me teh codez plx"-questions on SO by providing an answer.

Comment: @Dbl pls consider to not delete the question since the author didn't saw your message(he wasn't seen here since he posted the question), pls take in account that this is his first post here.

Comment: i am considering that. however your behaviour is the reason why stackoverflow is flooded with complete noobs littering the place with bad questions instead of getting into things by doing tutorials/browsing google. People like this op clearly put zero effort into solving their problem by themselves

Comment: @Dbl I am not asking for code. I just want to know the way it can be done.